# Codeigniter image upload validation with controller and function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image, codeigniter-3

I have a small issue on this code for the to add a product on my system I am using V_add_pro function, when the image upload part is coming I am facing some issues to validate, so that I used a different function to validate through callback, its not working. the main issue is i am saving the image name only to the database, so how to return the image name only?

```
  public function v_add_pro(){
    $this->load->model('B_menu');
    $data = array('status' => false, 'msg' => array());
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("pro_name", "name needed", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("pro_price", "price needed", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("pro_desc", "description is needed", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("dropzone", "select an image", "trim|required|callback_validate_image");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("pro_cat", "please select a category","callback_check_default|trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">','</p>');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $data['status'] = true;

        $pro_data = array(
            'pname' => $this->input->post('pro_name'),
            'pprice' => $this->input->post('pro_price'),
            'pdesc' => $this->input->post('pro_desc'),
            'pimage' =>$this->input->post('dropzone'),
            'catid' => $this->input->post('pro_cat'),
        );

        $this->B_menu->add($pro_data);

    } else {
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $data['msg'][$key] = form_error($key);
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

//to check the selected value for category

```
function check_default($post_string)
{
    return $post_string == '0' ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

//to upload the image to the correct path

```
public function validate_image() {
    $config = array(
        'allowed_types'=>'jpg|png|gif',
        'upload_path'=> realpath(APPPATH . '../skin/images'),
        'max_size'=>1
    );
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('dropzone'))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_image',$this->upload->display_errors());
    } else {
        $file_info = $this->upload->data();
        $img = $file_info['file_name'];
        return $img;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can You pls throw the error so that we can directly solve that

Answer (score 0):

```
public function validate_image()
{
 /* Start: Image Uploading */
            $baseurl = $this->config->base_url();
            $profile_photo = "";
            $profile_path = '';
            $config['upload_path'] = './assets/profile_pictures';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
            $config['max_size'] = '0';
            $config['max_width'] = '0';
            $config['max_height'] = '0';
            if (!empty($_FILES)) 
            {
                $this->file_ext = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $this->file_name = time() . "." . $this->file_ext;
                $config['file_name'] = $this->file_name;
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image', FALSE)) 
                {
                    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                    $this->form_validation->set_message('checkdoc', $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors());
                    if ($_FILES['image']['error'] != 4) 
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $profile_photo = $this->file_name;
                    $profile_path = $baseurl . "assets/profile_pictures";
                    return $profile_photo;
                }
            }

        /* End: Image Uploading */
```

To add-ons I am just saving file name as current timestamp thats it. Also return $imagename and also try to echo this

```
echo $this->upload->display_errors();
```

Comment: thanks mate, actually i am getting an error once i echo the display errors

Comment: Message: Object of class CI_Form_validation could not be converted to string

Comment: what is $profile_photo = "";
            $profile_path = '';
and the $baseurl also not working. i have edited the code also its not working.

Comment: I am just declaring those variables as for an initialization purpose thats it you can see at the else section I have used both of them.

Comment: still i am getting the same error, i tried your code also, but the file name is not getting?